# DNS Override for a specific subdomain only?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

I've got a 2k8 router working here, and it works great for the most part. I own a domain hosted at a remote datacenter and I'd like to override part of it. Let me explain:

www.mydomain.com is my Website
staging.mydomain.com is my Website's live staging copy hosted @ my DC, it's got pretty rigid accept/deny rules to lock it down to specific ips and whatnot.

beta.mydomain.com is an internal name that our internal development servers use to distinguish the site. (VirtualHost).

I'd like to override the dns for just beta.mydomain.com but i can't seem to figure out a way to do it without overriding the entire .mydomain.com record.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean you want to over ride it? What specifically are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy answer is to add an A record for beta into the zone for mydomain.com on your existing DNS server. Failing that however, you should be able to add a zone beta.mydomain.com to the DNS configuration on your DC. If all else fails, you can manually add the record to the HOSTS file ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29#Location_in_the_file_system for the location on your system).

Comment: Adding the zone `beta.mydomain.com` worked, thanks!